# How to make part of string bold and colored in android?

Tags: android

I have a string with some points which i get from storage model , I want to bold and color the point string only which i get from data storage model. How do i do that i have tried below mentioned code.

```
//Making a part of text from terms and condition spannable
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("App " + CWalletDataModel.getInstance().getS_szWalletBalance() + getString(R.string.points_text));
// Span to set text color to some RGB value
final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(RewardUtil.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorAccent));

// create a bold StyleSpan to be used on the SpannableStringBuilder
StyleSpan b = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold
// Set the text color for first 4 characters
sb.setSpan(fcs, 8, 8 + CWalletDataModel.getInstance().getS_szWalletBalance().length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
// set only the name part of the SpannableStringBuilder to be bold --> 16, 16 + name.length()
sb.setSpan(b, 8, 8 + CWalletDataModel.getInstance().getS_szWalletBalance().length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold


HomeScreenActivity.m_toolbarTitle.setText(sb);
```

Here i want only to bold "CWalletDataModel.getInstance().getS_szWalletBalance()".

Comment: you can use basic HTML tags, like `<b>`, `<font>` in the TextViews. Just use `HTML.fromHTML()`

Comment: what problem you are facing with the above code ?

Comment: Suppose CWalletModel....=5000 this 5000 not becom bold instead of "Ponts"

Answer (score 0):

That's because App + blank space is 4 characters("App "), not 8. Set the start for those 5000 at 4th position like you wrote in the comment and then spannable options would start after "App "

```
    sb.setSpan(fcs, 4, 4 + test.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    sb.setSpan(b, 4, 4 + test.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```